# About the quotient norm in the Calkin algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Recall that the Calkin algebra, is the quotient $B(H)/B_0(H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ and $B_0(H)$ are the algebra of bounded and compact operators on $H$.

Let $H$ be separable and $Q:B(H)\rightarrow B(H)/B_0(H)$ be a natural quotient map. Is it true for quotient norm that 
$$\|Q(T)\|=\lim_n\|T(I-P_n)\|$$
where $P_n$ is the projection on the span of the first $n$ elements in an orthonarmal basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $(P_n)$ is an approximate unit for the ideal of compact operators. If $C$ is any compact operator then $$\|T(I - P_n)\| \leq \|(T-C)(I-P_n)\| + \|C(I-P_n)\| \leq \|T - C\| + \|C - CP_n\|,$$ and $\|C - CP_n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so the norm in the Calkin algebra is achieved by taking the limit $\lim \|T(1 - P_n)\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this: If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $I$ is an ideal in $A$, then if $(e_\lambda)$ is any approximate unit of $I$, we have that the quotient norm satisfies $$\|a+I\|=\lim_{\lambda}\|a-ae_\lambda\|=\lim_{\lambda}\|a-e_\lambda a\| $$
for all $a\in A$ (this can be found in Murphy's book for example). In our case, $(P_n)$ is an approximate unit of $B_0(H)$, since $\|C-CP_n\|\to0$ for all compact operators.